# cURL - Use cURL to ftp files and keep the original timestamp of file

Tags: file, curl, timestamp, ftps

I am using curl to download some files from a FTPS site. When i download the files from site to my machine the zip files date changes to the download time and date. I want to keep the original timestamp that is on the FTPS server. 
Please advise how to do this. If you can provide examples that would be gr8 i am new to curl.

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

The key is this command line option:

```
   -R/--remote-time
          When  used,  this  will make libcurl attempt to figure out the
          timestamp of the remote file, and if that  is  available  make
          the local file get that same timestamp.
```

... which then can be used like:

```
curl -R -O --ssl ftp://example.com/that/file/I/want.txt
```

(--ssl was formerly known as --ftp-ssl)

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened. My zip files are still being downloaded with the new download time. This is what i did: curl -R myftpsite "my destination path"

Comment: Ok i figured out what im doing wrong. if i do the curl command without specifying a destination it saves the zip file in the current directory with the original timestamp. But if i specify a destination path is when the zip file is downloaded with the new time

Comment: In WSL I had to use `sudo curl ...` to avoid _Failed to set filetime: Operation not permitted_